# Linq try to using Include after groupBy

Tags: c#, .net

I have an Api in .net with EF, and the frontEnd needs to get the json in a particular way.
Originally i tried with this code:

```
[HttpGet("getTrafos")]

    public IEnumerable<object> GetTrafos(){
    var resultado =_context.Transformadores.OrderBy(z=>z.Anio).ThenBy(z=>z.Mes).ThenBy(x=>x.Prioridad)
      .Include(t => t.Etapa).ThenInclude(x=>x.IdColorNavigation)
      .Include(f=>f.Etapa).ThenInclude(x=>x.EtapaEmpleado)
      .ToList();

List<Object> array = new List<Object>();
      foreach(var result in resultado){
        result.Etapa=result.Etapa.OrderBy(m=>m.IdTipoEtapa).ToList();
        var mes = AsignarMes(resultado[0].Mes);      
        var obj=new {group = $"{mes} de {resultado[0].Anio}"};
        var ultimoAnio=resultado[0].Anio;
        var ultimoMes=mes;
        array.Add(obj);
        foreach(var trafo in resultado)
        {
            mes=this.AsignarMes(trafo.Mes);
            if(trafo.Anio!=ultimoAnio)
            {
            obj=new {group = $"{mes} de {resultado[0].Anio}"};
            array.Add(obj);
            array.Add(trafo);
            }
            else{
            if(mes!=ultimoMes)
            {
                obj=new{group=$"{mes} de {trafo.Anio}"};
                array.Add(obj);
            }
            array.Add(trafo);
            }
            
            ultimoAnio=trafo.Anio;
            ultimoMes=mes;
        }
      } 


      return array;
    }
```

AsignarMes Method:

```
private string AsignarMes(int? mes){
    var map = new Dictionary<int, string>() 
    {
        {1, "Enero"}, 
        {2, "Febrero"}, 
        {3, "Marzo"},
        {4,"Abril"},
        {5,"Mayo"},
        {6,"Junio"},
        {7,"Julio"},
        {8,"Agosto"},
        {9,"Septiembre"},
        {10,"Octubre"},
        {11,"Noviembre"},
        {12,"Diciembre"}

    };
    string output;
    return map.TryGetValue(mes.GetValueOrDefault(), out output) ? output : "";

    
    }
```

but for performance reasons (it takes 13 seconds aprox to download the content to the frontend) i tried with another way:

```
  var resultado =_context.Transformadores.OrderBy(z=>z.Anio).ThenBy(z=>z.Mes).ThenBy(x=>x.Prioridad)
      .GroupBy(x=> new { x.Anio, x.Mes }, (key, group) => new 
            { 
                Anio = key.Anio,
                Mes = key.Mes,
                Trafos = group.ToList()
            });

      List<Object> array = new List<Object>();

      foreach (var result in resultado) {
          foreach (var trafo in result.Trafos)
          {
            trafo.Etapa = trafo.Etapa.OrderBy(m => m.IdTipoEtapa).ToList();
          }
          
          var mesEnLetras = this.AsignarMes(result.Mes);
          var obj = new {group = $"{mesEnLetras} de {result.Anio}"};

          array.Add(obj);
          array.AddRange(result.Trafos);
      }

      return array;
```

The performance was better with this last code but the problem is that i can´t Include *Etapa*, *IdColorNavigation* and *EtapaEmpleado*.
Is there another way to do this?

Theese are the Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Foha.Models
{
    public partial class Transformadores
    {
        public Transformadores()
        {
            Etapa = new HashSet<Etapa>();
        }

        public int IdTransfo { get; set; }
        public string OPe { get; set; }
        public int? OTe { get; set; }
        public string Observaciones { get; set; }
        public int RangoInicio { get; set; }
        public int RangoFin { get; set; }
        public int? IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string NombreCli { get; set; }
        public int Potencia { get; set; }
        public int? IdTipoTransfo { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FechaCreacion { get; set; }
        public int? Mes { get; set; }
        public int? Anio { get; set; }
        public int? Prioridad { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente IdClienteNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual TipoTransfo IdTipoTransfoNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Etapa> Etapa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Foha.Models
{
    public partial class Etapa
    {
        public Etapa()
        {
            EtapaEmpleado = new HashSet<EtapaEmpleado>();
        }

        public int IdEtapa { get; set; }
        public int? IdTipoEtapa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateIni { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateFin { get; set; }
        public bool? IsEnded { get; set; }
        public string TiempoParc { get; set; }
        public string TiempoFin { get; set; }
        public int? IdTransfo { get; set; }
        public string IdEmpleado { get; set; }
        public string Hora { get; set; }
        public DateTime? InicioProceso { get; set; }
        public int? IdColor { get; set; }
        public int? NumEtapa { get; set; }

        public virtual Colores IdColorNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual TipoEtapa IdTipoEtapaNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Transformadores IdTransfoNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EtapaEmpleado> EtapaEmpleado { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't just write the `include()`'s right after `_context.Transformadores.`? If indeed, you might try it with `Trafos = group.Select(t => new { Trafo = t, Etapa = t.Etapa, ...})ToList()`.

Comment: Sorry for being late!...I didn´t realize that i could write the `Include()` after `_context.Transformadores`, Thanks for help me!.